# File Share Witness with 4 Node Cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering, high-availability, failover, hadr

I am building a cluster of 4 nodes along with a file share witness. Every month due to server updates the  server that holds the file share will need to be rebooted. My question is while the file share becomes unavailable during that time will the cluster go down?

Comment: What is version of Windows server ?,  please add that in the question.

Comment: Direct answer, if *only* the FS witness is down cluster will not come down. It still has 4 votes assuming all are voting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the cluster will not go down until a node cannot form quorum.  Assuming all four nodes have a quorum vote, there are five possible votes.  Accordingly a node will have to get three votes to maintain or gain quorum.  When the file share witness goes offline, the node that currently owns quorum will maintain ownership because it can still get four votes.

See [Understanding Quorum in a Failover Cluster](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2011/05/27/understanding-quorum-in-a-failover-cluster/) for the long answer.